# API request forbidden when requesting from same domain

Tags: rest-api, wp-api

I have a custom API endpoint that is rejecting calls being made from the same domain.

EG: I can request `.../wp-json/darts/v1/venues` from Postman (or CURL) and get a 200 response and the expected list of venues.

However, if I request the same endpoint from the same domain (either from within the WP theme or just a static HTML file) if rejects it with the following error:

```
{
    "code": "rest_forbidden",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

The `permission_callback` I'm using is:

```
'permission_callback' => function () {
    return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
}
```

If I remove the `permission_callback` the request is always successful.

The request is made using fetch (but also tested with CURL, though Postman etc...)

```
// App password from wp-admin
const authCreds = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + appPassword);
fetch("https://example.com/darts/v1/venues", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: authCreds,
    },
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) =>  ( console.log(data));
```

Any help or advice appreciated :)

Comment: If it was a CORS issue it's unlikely you'd receive a JSON response from the REST API as CORS is a browser level technology not a WP technology. Without seeing the code you are using to make the request it's difficult to know what went wrong. This may also be related to the JWT plugin

Comment: what is your `permission_callback` callbacks code? Please edit your question to include the code

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell Added missing code :)

Comment: you sure the problem isn't the bearer token? The docs for that plugin involve fetching a token from the JWT endpoint. Note that JWT is offtopic here, unless this can be answered without any involvement with JWT it makes the question offtopic. This isn't a place to get help with 3rd party plugins. As far as I can tell, you're using a plugin to do authentication and when you try to use the REST API it says you can't do that because you're not authenticated. The usual advice of making sure you have a logged in cookies session and REST API nonce don't seem to apply here as a result

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell - It isn't the plugin as the authentication works from a remote request and...

I have now recreated the same issue using Basic Auth (with App Password) so will try and get help using that as a basis - thanks :)

Comment: does that mean you have a logged in cookie session and the REST API nonce?